# How to fix "Internal server error" while storing emojis with text

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-rds, collation

I am making RESTful API for Mobile device and use `node js` for. My database is `MySQL 5.7.24`. But when any request with emojis in it throws `"Internal server error"`. I have changes whole database to `utf8mb4` and columns to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. Where I am getting wrong?

I.E:
Assume that my `table` is having two columns `(Id, Review)`, when I get request for data like `(2,'OkThisIsFine')` its working, but when the request is like `(3,'ThisIsNOTwork☹')` then it shows `"Internal server error".`

Comment: Maybe you make a `set names utf8` when you open the connection to the DB? If that is the case you need to change it to `set names utf8mb4`

Comment: @AlonEitan can you elaborate little more?

Comment: _"After a connection has been established, clients can change the character set and collation system variables for the current session"_ ([Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html#charset-connection-sql-statements)) - Maybe you set a different  character set from your code (utf8 instead of utf8mb4)?

Comment: I haven't set any names in my code while creating connection @AlonEitan

Comment: You need to provide a minimum example for us to replicate the issue and help you

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, sorry. I didn't downvote BTW

Comment: @Yeikel example added .

Comment: @DhruvPatadia Can you try and run `set names utf8mb4` before you store the emojes? Right after you created the connection

Comment: @AlonEitan didn't worked :(

Comment: Can you trace to see what the exception is ? Internal server error should output  more details in the back end

Comment: @Yeikel the error is like this
[addReview]Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x82' for column 'in_review' at row 1 
in_review(varchar (250)) is my input parameter in store procedure to add a review.

Answer (score 0):

The 11th comment finally gives enough info to answer the question.

When you created that Stored Procedure, you were not using `utf8mb4`.  To prove that (or shoot down my Answer), do `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name`.  Near the end it will say, for example `character_set_client: utf8`.  Rebuild it:

```
DROP PROCEDURE ...;
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
DELIMITER //
CREATE ... PROCEDURE ...
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have tried SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name and ot shows my character_set_client is utf8mb4
my collation connection is utf8mb4_general_ci and my database collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: @DhruvPatadia - Rats!  Then the problem is somewhere else.  Check connection parameters, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, anything that `REST` is doing, etc.